# Laravel - a good way to get db data depending on language

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm programming a backend in which the admin can edit different texts for the frontend.

The website has about 20-30 different text passages and these are to be displayed in the respective language, depending on whether the user selects English or German in the frontend.

For different text languages I usually used the Laravel language packs. However, since the data is to be changed in the backend, I have to dynamically get the data from the database, depending on the selected language.

Now I'm looking for a good way to get the right data from the database without having to make a database query for each text passage.

Database dummy data looks like this:

[image]

With this code:

```
$helloText = Texts::where(
            'title', 'hello')->where(
            'code', Config::get('app.locale'))->first();
$aboutText = Texts::where(
            'title', 'about')->where(
            'code', Config::get('app.locale'))->first();
```

These 2 requests are for 2 text passages. I would have to do the same for 20-30 other text passages at the moment. I wanted to ask if there would be a better way to summarize them all in one query by specifying all the "titles" I need for this blade.

Or maybe another way. There need's to be another way to do that, without allways doing 20-30 querys. At least I hope for another way.

And if someone know's a better way, I would love to see how I output the correct data in the correct place in the view. Because I haven't found a better way right now..

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load all the translations with one query:

```
$texts = Texts::whereIn('title', ['hello', 'about'])
     ->where('code', config('app.locale'))
     ->get()
```

And then just use this collection. For example, you can use the [`firstWhere()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-first-where) method:

```
{{ $texts->firstWhere('title', 'hello')->text }}
```

Comment: If you go with this approach I would recommend you make a global translation function to use in the views, which could rely on a singleton class to retrieve the data from the database and use caching for your translations to reduce the amount of queries made to the DB!

Comment: `$texts->firstWhere('title', 'hello')->text` will not create any additional queries and it's short enough.

Answer (score 2):

This requirement is something that is not new, you could rely on existing solutions tackling the same problem.
I suggest you take a look at the `translation` composer package by `waavi`, see:

[waavi/translation](https://github.com/Waavi/translation)

That should be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: thats just another way to get the different if they are in laravel, not from the database

Comment: How so? From the description: `This package allows you to load translation from the regular Laravel localization files (in /resources/lang), from the database, from cache or in a mix of the previous` - I am using exactly that package to retrieve my translations from the database!

Comment: oh yes, you're right :) Thanks for that but the answer from @Alexey is the best one for my case :) Thanks anyways :D

Comment: The advantage is that you can just do `trans('some.key.name')` and it will automatically figure out if there is such a key in the files, if not it will proceed to look in the database.